# Inputmask Yii2 не выводит значение

Tags: yii2, inputmask

Использую следующий код для поля с номером телефона

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone')
         ->textInput(['value'=>$info['phone']])
         ->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
             'mask' => '+7 (999)-999-9999',
         ]); ?>
```

Вопрос: почему не выводится телефон? То есть, его сохраняет в базу, но при выводе не показывает

Comment: а почему не просто textInput()? что у Вас в $model?

Comment: @WebCoder Наоборот, зачем ещё нужен `textInput()` и что за переменная `$info`? Возможно все требуемые вам данные содержаться в `$model` и вам просто стоит убрать `textInput()` и все заработает.

Comment: @NPreston Ну вообще-то textInput() это тип поля по умолчанию. вы по сути предложили то что и я)

Comment: в $info у меня данные пользователя. сейчас написал так <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
                                'mask' => '+7 (999)-999-9999',
                                'value' => $info['phone']
                            ]); ?>, но не работает всеравно

Comment: @Diefair зачем вам `$info` туда вставлять, у вас в самой модели что-ли нет данных? напишите рядышком `<?= $model->phone ?>`, покажется ли телефон? Если нет, то вы явно что-то скрываете: опишите подробнее, зачем вам `$info`, и как вы все это дело сохраняете

Answer (score 0):

Делаться так!

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone')
     ->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
         'mask' => '+7 (999)-999-9999',
     ])->textInput(['value'=>'+79000000000']); ?>
```

По умолчание 
в инпуте +79000000000